# How to treat a hyphen as a part of a whole word

Tags: notepad++

I work in a firm where we are using hyphens inside names for variables. For readability reasons, Notepad++ is used for editing purposes.

This causes issues while searching for variables, as you can see here:

variable name = "var-1"

Piece of source code:

```
function f-var-1 (INPUT l-var-1):
...
end function.
...
<do-something-with(var-1)>
...
```

When I want to see what's done with variable `var-1`, I only want to see the line with the `do-something`, but, even when checking `whole words`, also fragments of `f-var-1` and `l-var-1` are highlighted, because of the hyphen.

Does anybody know how to handle this?

**Edit**

Also, when I double-click on a name, containing a hyphen, I want the whole word (including the parts before or after the hyphen) to be highlighed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add any character to be part of a word.

> Menu > Settings > Preferences > Delimiter

- Check "Add your character as part of word"
- Just add an hyphen
- <kbd>Close</kbd>

**Preferences:**

[image]

**In action (when you double-click on `var-1`):**

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Dominique: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

- Find what: `[^-]var-1`
- Search Mode: Regular expressions

This will search for `var-1` unless it's preceded by a dash. (if `var-1` is it at the beginning of the file, it will also not be found)

Comment: Although this might work, I prefer altering my settings in such a way that a hyphen gets treated as a regular letter, so that I can simply search for "var-1".

Comment: @Dominique That would involve changing the regex parser used by NP++.

Comment: No, I'm not even planning of using regular expressions search mode, just a regular search mode.

Comment: This is matching `othervar-123`

Comment: @Toto you're right, maybe something like `[( ]var-1` (round bracket or space) would be better, but I don't know which characters in this language are used as actual word boundaries

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Note: this answer was published when the question looked like this: [revision 2](https://superuser.com/revisions/1617194/2). The answer may or may not be expanded in the future to address what has been added to the question since.</sub>

---

Matching `var-1` as a whole word is equivalent to

- `\bvar-1\b` regular expression, where `\b` matches a word boundary;
- or to `(?<!\w)var-1(?!\w)` where `\w` matches a word character, `(?<!…)` and `(?!…)` are negative lookbehind and negative lokahead respectively.

The latter form can easily be adjusted to treat `-` like `\w`:

```
(?<![\w-])var-1(?![\w-])
```

Don't forget to check the "regular expression" checkbox.

Comment: I just gonna post same answer ;)

Comment: Both your options also match `f-var-1` so it doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Berend Do you mean "both options equivalent to the original search"? Yes they do, because they are meant to be *equivalent* to the original search. The final *adjusted* expression does not match `f-var-1`. This is my answer.

Comment: Right, the way it's written now looks like your bullet points are already an answer. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can change the characters NP++ uses as word characters to include `-`. In order to do that, you need to install the NppExec plugin first.

Select Plugins → NppExec → Execute and type the command:

`sci_sendmsg 2077  0 @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-_"`

Now you can search for `var-1` with the option *Whole word only*, and Search Mode: *Normal*.

Note that this stops working when switching to a different tab, so you need to re-run the command (Ctrl+F6). The link below mentions using NppScripting, but I'm not familiar with that.

For more details, see here: https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/993b6ab9/

Comment: The behaviour is indeed exactly what I'm looking for, but, as mentioned on the URL, it only seems to work on the tab you're currently working on, and once changing the tab (even just go and go back) seems to disable that behaviour. Unfortunately I also have no knowledge of NPP scripting, so I have no idea on how to go from here.

Comment: As this now becomes a "Notepad++" programming question (how to send SCI_SENDMSG commands for the whole Notepad++ application), I'll start a new discussion about this on StackOverflow.